# default query parameter integer 0 value in RAML

Tags: mulesoft, raml, anypoint-platform

I have created a query parameter with a default integer 0 value in RAML and in Exchange this value not displayed. Could anyone help with it?
Example RAML

```
uriParameters:
  page:
    required: true
    displayName: page
    description: page
    type: integer
    default: 0
    example:
      0
  size:
    required: true
    displayName: size
    description: size
    type: integer
    default: 100
    example:
      100
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with the API Console when the `default`/`example` is set to `0`.  If you change the `default` to a non-zero value, then the API Console from within the API Designer or the Exchange displays the value.